# How to change query plan before execution (possibly turning an optimization off)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple spark SQL query :

```
SELECT x, y
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.key = t2.key
WHERE expensiveFunction(t1.key)
```

Where `expensiveFunction` is a spark UDF (User-defined function).

When I look at the query plan generated by spark, I see that **it has two *filter* operations** instead of just one: it checks not only `expensiveFunction(t1.key)`, but also `expensiveFunction(t2.key)`.

[image]

In general, this optimization is not a bad thing, because it reduces the number of records to join, and joining is an expensive operation. But in my case `expensiveFunction(t2.key)` always returns true, so I would like to remove it.

Is there a way to change the query plan before executing a query ? Is there a way to indicate to spark that I don’t want a given optimization to be applied to my query ?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because of the optimizer rule `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.InferFiltersFromConstraints`
Code comments is as follows([github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/QueryPlanConstraints.scala#L58))

```
  /**
   * Infers an additional set of constraints from a given set of equality constraints.
   * For e.g., if an operator has constraints of the form (`a = 5`, `a = b`), this returns an
   * additional constraint of the form `b = 5`.
   */
  def inferAdditionalConstraints(constraints: Set[Expression]): Set[Expression]
```

You could disable this Optimizer rule using `spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules`

> val OPTIMIZER_EXCLUDED_RULES = buildConf("spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules")
>      .doc("Configures a list of rules to be disabled in the optimizer, in which the rules are " +
>        "specified by their rule names and separated by comma. It is not guaranteed that all the " +
>        "rules in this configuration will eventually be excluded, as some rules are necessary " +
>        "for correctness. The optimizer will log the rules that have indeed been excluded.")
>      .stringConf
>      .createOptional
>   That way the filter will not get propagated to both sids of join

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to change the query plan before executing a query?

In general, yes. There are few extension points in Spark SQL query planner and optimizer that would make the wish doable

> Is there a way to indicate to spark that I don’t want a given optimization to be applied to my query ?

That's nearly impossible unless the optimization allows for that. In other words you'd have to find out whether the rule has an option to turn it off, e.g. `CostBasedJoinReorder` with `spark.sql.cbo.enabled` or `spark.sql.cbo.joinReorder.enabled` configuration properties (when [either is off `CostBasedJoinReorder` does nothing](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/CostBasedJoinReorder.scala#L40)).

You could write a custom logical operator that would make the optimization void (as it would not be matched given unknown logical operator) and at optimization phase you'd remove it.

Use [extendedOperatorOptimizationRules](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala#L92) to register custom optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this query like below to avoid the extra function call.

```
SELECT x, y
FROM (SELECT <required-columns> FROM t1 WHERE expensiveFunction(t1.key)) t0 INNER JOIN t2 ON t0.key = t2.key
```

To be extra sure you can persist this query (`SELECT FROM t1 WHERE expensiveFunction(t1.key)`) as a separate DataFrame. and then join table `t2` with this DataFrame.

For example lets say we have DataFrames `df1` and `df2` for table `t1` and `t2` respectively. we do the something like the following to avoid the `expensiveFunction` call twice.

```
val df3 = df1.filter("col1 == 1") 
df3.persist() // forces evaluation of this dataframe and applies the expensive function filter on df1.
df3.createOrReplaceTempView("t1")
spark.sql("""SELECT t1.col1. t2.col2
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.col1""") // this query now have no reference to expensiveFunction
```

Comment: Saving as a separate Dataframe doesn't work, I tried it. Dataframes are lazy objects and the query planner has access to their dependencies. I am going to try it with a subquery, but I think the optimizer will see the possible optimization anyway.

Comment: in the separate dataframe you will to call the method `persist()`. if you call the method persist that dataframe evaluation is forced and then you can join this persisted dataframe with the other dataframe and you join query will have no reference to `expensiveFunction` function

Comment: This is a good idea, and indeed prevents spark to perform its unwanted optimization. However, it adds the cost of persisting a large dataset and then immediately reading it... So, if anyone knows how to disable an optimization directly from the query planner, I’d be glad to hear it.